# How to properly cherry pick problematic commits from linux kernel git tree

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

**Background**

I have a device that is not working properly starting from Linux Kernel Version 4.12 and above. I want to find out which specific commit caused the issue. My current flow is:

1. View the linux kernel commit log at [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/?h=v4.12-rc1&ofs=450)
2. Clicking on the individual commit, copy the commit id
3. Run `git checkout <commit id>`
4. Reconfigure the kernel `make menuconfig`, and recompile `make -j32`
5. Install the kernel on my device, confirm whether the issue is still persist
6. If not, narrow the range of the commits, go back to step 1

**The Problem**

While I was going through this tedious process, I found that the compiled kernel version was different (You can also view this via reading the `Makefile`). **However, I do not see version changes via the linux kernel commit log.** In fact, after trying `git diff <first commit id> <second commit id>`, where the second commit id is 1 commit behind the first one according to the linux kernel commit log in step 1, it was found that there are changes that is not reflected on the website.

**Question**

Why is this going on? How should I properly find out the specific commit that caused an issue on my device?

Comment: You probably is trying to play with *merge* commit while the commit in question is *non-merge*. Below answer points to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to properly find out which commit caused an issue on your device you should use `git bisect`. It automates the workflow you have been doing manually. See documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect).

> This command uses a binary search algorithm to find which commit in
>   your project’s history introduced a bug. You use it by first telling
>   it a "bad" commit that is known to contain the bug, and a "good"
>   commit that is known to be before the bug was introduced. Then git
>   bisect picks a commit between those two endpoints and asks you whether
>   the selected commit is "good" or "bad". It continues narrowing down
>   the range until it finds the exact commit that introduced the change.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out. But it still does not answer the question of why the commit log from the website does not same with `git diff`. I have manually identified the commit id that caused the issue, but I am still unable to find out which commit that produced/modified the problematic file that caused the bug.